# Tangent line to the curve

Tags: calculus, curves, tangent-line

Write the equations off the tangent line and normal line to the curve:
$$x = e^t\cos(t)$$
$$y = e^t\sin(t)$$
at the point A(1,0).
Do I take $x(t_0) = 0$ and $y(t_0) = 1$?
I solved it this way and I got the tangent line:
$$(x-e\cos(1))/(e(\sin(1)-\cos(1))) = (y-0)/1$$
Is this correct or do I have to find $t_0$ in another way?

Comment: Yes, you are correct in your interpretation

Comment: Okay perfect, I have one more question, if I want to find the equation of the tangent line to the curve:
x = (t+2)/(3t+4)
y = (4t+3)/(2t+1)
t belongs to R \ {-4/3 , -1/2}
Which is passing through O(0,0). Do I take x(t0) = 0 and y(t0) = 0? Or do I need to write x = 0 and y = 0 and find a different t0 for each? Thank you in advance

Comment: Your new curve $x = \frac{t+2}{3t+4}, y = \frac{4t+3}{2t+1}$ will pass through through the origin $O = (0,0)$ if and only if $\exists t_0$ such that $x(t_0) = 0 = y(t_0)$

Comment: But I think the question asks to find the equation of the tangent line to the given curve such that the tangent line passes through $(0,0)$. In that case, you need to compute derivatives of $x, y$ first to get the tangent line, and since it passes through the origin, the y-intercept is 0, therefore the  tangent line equation will have the form $y = mx$, where m is $\frac{dy}{dx}$

Comment: This does not seem correct. Point $(0, 1)$ is not even on the given curve. Did you mean $(1, 0)$? In that case, yes but then the equation of the tangent line is not correct.

Comment: Yes, I'm sorry I must've edited by mistake, it's (1,0). I think I know why it's not correct, I have to find t0, which would now be 0, so the equation of the tangent line is:
(x-1)/1 = y/1
If this isn't correct could you please explain? Thanks a lot!

Comment: $y = x - 1$ is correct.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First you have to find the parameter $t$ for which
$$c(t)=e^t\cdot\begin{pmatrix}\cos(t)\\\sin(t)\end{pmatrix}=\begin{pmatrix}1\\0\end{pmatrix}.$$
An easy calculation shows that $t=0$.  As
$$\dot c(t)=e^t\cdot\begin{pmatrix}\cos(t)-\sin(t)\\\sin(t)+\cos(t)\end{pmatrix}$$
the tangent vector in $t=0$ is
$$\dot c(0)=e^0\cdot\begin{pmatrix}1+0\\0+1\end{pmatrix}
=\begin{pmatrix}1\\1\end{pmatrix}$$
the tangent's equation is
$$\begin{pmatrix}x\\y\end{pmatrix}
=\begin{pmatrix}1\\0\end{pmatrix}+s\begin{pmatrix}1\\1\end{pmatrix}
$$
or $y=x-1$.

Answer (score 0):

For your second question, define
$$c(t)=\begin{pmatrix}
\frac{t+2}{3t+4}\\\frac{4t+3}{2t+1}
\end{pmatrix}.$$
Compute
$$\dot c(t)=-2\begin{pmatrix}
\frac{1}{(3t+4)^2}\\\frac{1}{(2t+1)^2}
\end{pmatrix}.$$
The tangent line passes through the origin iff $\dot c(t)$ is parallel to $c(t)$. From here you'll arrive in solving
$$(t+2)(3t+4)=(4t+3)(2t+1),$$
which has the solutions $t=\pm1$.